# Magento html image import via Magmi?

Tags: magento, magmi

Does anyone know how to import images from an html link using Magmi? Can you give show me a screen shot of how the links are suppose to work? I have tried on my end a couple different ways and can not get it to work. Below is a screen shot link of my current import process using magmi.

http://screencast.com/t/3cvknc8cQ

Comment: Is the product directory in media/import/ ? That's where Magmi will be looking for it.

Comment: Yes there is but I want to just use a standard html link because the image is from another website. I tried putting the links but it did not work.

Comment: Lol. I just Googled it and found an answer.....which I wrote - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/does-magmi-can-able-to-download-remote-images

Answer (score 0):

In order to import images you need to call the with the full url path like this:

```
"sku""image","small_image"
"4015","http://www.yoururl.com/skin/frontend/default/themename/images/02.jpg","http://www.yoururl.com/skin/frontend/default/themename/images/"
```

also you can add the thumbnail column with the image url.